# mostrar el menor resultado de calculo de una consulta

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, php7

disculpen mis molestias, tengo una consulta sql en la cual me muestra varias filas, sobre datos capturados de precios de productos y gastos de envio.
Entonces mediante calculos matematicos busco cual es el producto que me convendria traer ya que son de diferentes tiendas en donde venden el mismo producto.
Hasta ese punto si he conseguido sacar los calculos, pero lo que quisiera es que solo me muestre cual es el producto con menor resultado segun mi calculo, y no todos los productos relacionados con cada id que contiene la tabla.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registraproductos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. "<br>Producto:" . $row["producto"]. "<br>Precio" . $row["precio"]. "<br>Gastos de Envio:" . $row["gastos_envio"]. "<br>";

$midinero= 2000; 
$gastosdenvio= $row["gastos_envio"];
$resultado=$midinero-$gastosdenvio;

echo "El menor resultado es:".$resultado."";

?>
```

---

Voy a tratar de ser mas breve, haber si alguien me comprende.
lo que hace el codigo es mostrar los resultados de la consulta, agregandole una operacion con un echo, para que me diga cual es el menor resultado de todas las operaciones, pero me muestra todos los redultados que encontro la consulta. Y no solo el menor resultado de la operacion.

Osea que me muetra:

El menor resultado es:4000
El menor resultado es:2600
El menor resultado es:3500

Cuando solo me deberia mostrar:
El menor resultado es:2600

---

Este es el codigo corregido en donde me sale el error.
storage/emulated/0/000web/registraproductos/procesamientos/menoresultado.php on line 39 -500 cuando el valor menor es 2600.

```
<?php 
include "conexion.php";

$dbname = "base_datos";



// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registraproductos"; $result = $conn->query($sql); 
$masBajo = array("producto" => "", "precio" => 0, "gastos_envio" => 0); //Usaremos este array para ir guardando los datos del producto con el menor resultado 
$midinero = 2000; 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
// output data of each row
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
$resultado = $midinero - $row['gastos_envio']; 
if ($masBajo['producto'] != "") { //Comprobamos si ya tenemos algun producto guardado en el array
if ($resultado < ($midinero - $masBajo['gastos_envio'])) { //Comprobamos si el resultado es menor al resultado del producto ya guardado en el array si lo es 
$masBajo["producto"] = $row["producto"]; 
$masBajo["precio"] = $row["precio"];
$masBajo["gastos_envio"] = $row["gastos_envio"];
 }
  } else { //Como no tenemos guardado ningun producto, guardamos el actual 
$masBajo["producto"] = $row["producto"]; 
$masBajo["precio"] = $row["precio"];
$masBajo["gastos_envio"] = $row["gastos_envio"];
 }
  }
echo "El menor resultado es:".$midinero-$masBajo['gastos_envio']."";
 } else {

  echo "0 results";

}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: No queda claro lo que buscas lograr, por ejemplo nos muestras una consulta general y no vemos los cálculos que mencionas, por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Si el calculo lo haces a nivel de SQL, una solución fácil y rápida es agregar lo siguiente a tu query:

```
ORDER BY nombre_de_la_columna_con_el_resultado ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Otra opción mas elegante es usar

```
MIN(nombre_de_la_columna_con_el_resultado)
```

Comment: No es que sea mas elegante, de hecho tienen sus implicaciones ambas, por ejemplo si usas la segunda puede ser que el OP necesite agrupar si obtiene mínimos por cada producto y en caso de obtener mínimos por cada producto entonces aún así puede ser que deba ocupar `ORDER BY`

Comment: Buen punto, gracias por la aclaración

Comment: te agradesco tu ayuda, pero lo que yo busco es que me encuentre el menor resultado. Osea realizar la consulta y de ahi hacer la operacion y de todas esas operaciones que se realizen sacar el menor resultado.

Answer (score 0):

¿No te valdría tener una variable en la que vayas guardando los datos del row con menos resultado y en cada iteración del while, realizar la operación y con el restultado de la misma, comprobar si ese resultado es menor al que tienes guardado en la variable y si es así sustiur los datos de la variable por los datos nuevos?

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registraproductos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$masBajo = array("producto" => "", "precio" => 0, "gastos_envio" => 0); //Usaremos este array para ir guardando los datos del producto con el menor resultado
$midinero = 2000;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultado = $midinero - $row['gastos_envio'];
        if ($masBajo['producto'] != "") {
            //Comprobamos si ya tenemos algun producto guardado en el array
            if ($resultado < ($midinero - $masBajo['gastos_envio'])) {
                //Comprobamos si el resultado es menor al resultado del producto ya guardado en el array si lo es
                $masBajo["producto"] = $row["producto"];
                $masBajo["precio"] = $row["precio"];
                $masBajo["gastos_envio"] = $row["gastos_envio"];
            }
        } else {
            //Como no tenemos guardado ningun producto, guardamos el actual
            $masBajo["producto"] = $row["producto"];
            $masBajo["precio"] = $row["precio"];
            $masBajo["gastos_envio"] = $row["gastos_envio"];
        }
    }

    echo "El menor resultado es:".$midinero-$masBajo['gastos_envio']."";
}
```

Está sería la manera más rápida y sencilla que se me ocurre con el código que nos aportas.

Comment: si algo es masomenos lo que busco, pero me sale este error: 
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /storage/emulated/0/000web/registraproductos/procesamientos/menoresultado.php on line 39
-500 
cuando el valor menor es 2600.

Comment: Sin ver el código es imposible que te podamos ayudar con ese error.